# How to slow supervisord restarting processes?

Tags: supervisord

I can't see any way to keep supervisord from pausing a second before restarting a process. I use crashmail, so everytime something minor happens to a running process I get around 10 email/minute. I'd really like to restrict it to restarting a process say once or twice a minute.

Does anyone happen to know how to do that? I looked around and didn't see an obvious solution, other than having the managed scripts pause when starting (before doing anything), which really isn't feasible for this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing value for `startretries`? By default it's 3, so you shouldn't get so many emails.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea, since by then I'd be pretty notified of the problem.

Comment: I don't actually have any value at all set for that...

Comment: According to documentation default value is 3 but your supervisord behaves as it has much higher value. Try adjusting it and see what has changed.